# Latex Compilation Error on Overleaf - It just shows the source code in another theme instead of the pdf of the compiled output

Tags: overleaf

I am working on an academic paper on Overleaf. When I make a copy of the working, existing project to make some edits, I can not see the compiled document - It simply shows me the source code in another format. I cannot even toggle error log file. Can anyone please help me to identify the cause of this? TIA

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! From your description is /unfortunately) unclear what you doing. Overleaf always show compilation result, or  report an error if for some reason cannot compile your file.

Comment: Please add a full minimal working example (MWE).

Comment: If you suspect an issue with the overleaf site rather than your document, there is nothing we can do here, ask a question emailed to the overleaf support address.

Comment: This is an Overleaf question, so yes please contact Overleaf Support: https://www.overleaf.com/contact. I'm on the support team, and we don't mind answering questions like this. It sounds like you have a browser plugin installed that is interfering with the PDF viewer (something like "Overleaf Text Area Extension"). Please contact support for troubleshooting suggestions.